# PDF related to sonar-runner in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have installed 3.7.4 Sonar server in my machine. And also installed PDF plugin in the server. I also installed sonar-runner-2.4. And run the sonar runner on java project. Now, I can see the metrics in WebInterface of Sonar server(by using `localhost:9000`). But, I need to generated PDF of this metrics. I unable to find where download option is available. Can any body help to move forward.

Note: PDF plugin is already installed